# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect() ubuntu cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu-14.04

I am coding in CakePHP. I am getting an error message - "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ldap_connect()". I am using Ubuntu and PHP version is PHP 5.6.31. I have already installed ldap using this command-

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ldap
```

Restarted the Apache server-

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I have also uncommented the following line from php.ini -

```
extension=php_ldap.dll
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem? Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the package with `sudo php5enmod ldap`?

Comment: If you're using PHP as a FCGI (i.e. php-fpm) you'll need to restart the PHP process as well

Comment: Yes I have enabled the package

Comment: Make sure your extension is loaded or not. `php -m`